# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"

Tags: 8, entities

There are some posts about this error for Drupal 7, but I'm using Drupal 8.1 and those solutions don't work for D8.

I tried [this patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2303847#comment-10848446) (coded for D7) and doesn't work.

The effect of the error is that QuickEdit doesn't work: sometimes the quick edit link doesn't appears, sometimes it appears but when edit some fields I get error.

Can anybody help?

**UPDATE for neograph**:
I haven't changed anything about the loading of the javascript. The only thing I did is edit the `my_theme.libraries.yml` for adding JS plugins:

```
global-css:
  css:
    theme:
      #css/style.css: { }
      dist/css/style.css: { }

global-js:
  js:
    #js/script.js: { }
    bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js: { }
    bower_components/slicknav/dist/jquery.slicknav.min.js: { }
    bower_components/superfish/dist/js/superfish.min.js: { }
    dist/js/script.js: { }
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

Comment: Do you have changed anything in the loading of the javascript? Modules like [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) can cause this if configured incorrectly.

Comment: @Neograph734: could you check the Update on my question post? Thanks

Comment: I am still on D7 so I might not be the right person for this, but it does seem to have something to with JavaScript loading in the wrong order, or a missing dependency. Or perhaps your plugins are conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in panels module, upgrade to latest version to fix the issue.
For more details see https://www.drupal.org/node/2713123

Answer (score 0):

add `defer` to js files. When present, it specifies that the script is executed when the page has finished parsing.

```
global-css:
 css:
 theme:
   #css/style.css: { }
   dist/css/style.css: { }

global-js:
 js:
   #js/script.js: { }
   bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js: { attributes: { defer: true } }
   bower_components/slicknav/dist/jquery.slicknav.min.js: { attributes: { defer: true } }
   bower_components/superfish/dist/js/superfish.min.js: { attributes: { defer: true } }
   dist/js/script.js: { attributes: { defer: true } }
dependencies:
 - core/jquery
```